# Como concatenar texto plano + item (JSON) - REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando concatenar texto con unas `props` pasadas por parametro a un componente.

Estos parámetros son recibidos desde un `json-server` y son pasados a través del padre como `props`.

```
import * as Icons from 'react-icons';
import React from 'react';

function MenuItem({id,title}){
return(
<li>
    <Icons. `${title}` />
</li>
);
}
export default MenuItem;
```

**Salida --> Error**

**Salida esperada -> El icono**

He probado diferentes soluciones, pero no son las que busco. Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradeceria.

Comment: La estructura es correcta? `<Icons.`? Que dice el error?

Comment: @JuanRivera Creo que el OP está tratando de hacer algo como `Icons[title]`

Answer (score 0):

Para *concatenar texto plano con un item (JSON)* (entendiendo item como propiedad) puedes utilizar [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) como veo que tratas de poner en tu ejemplo. Por ejemplo:

```js
const datos={
  nombre: "Juan",
  edad:"25"
}

console.log(`Esto es texto simple, con la propiedad nombre de los datos, que es: ${datos.nombre}`)
```

Viendo la documentación de [react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons) creo que el verdadero problema es un error ligado al uso incorrecto de la librería **(Sería de infinita ayuda que edites tu pregunta con el error que obtienes, esto ahorraría muchísimo trabajo para deducir que es lo que está pasando)**.

Combinando el primer ejemplo de la librería con tu documentación creo que debería de verse así lo que andas buscando:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {FaBeer} from 'react-icons/fa';


function MenuItem({
  id,
  title
}) {
  return ( 
  < li >
    < FaBee/> { title }
  </li>
  );
}
export default MenuItem;
```

En este caso creo un item de un menu que consta de un texto y un icono, el texto es proveído en el prop llamado `title` y el ícono proviene de `react-icons`, es importante resaltar que para escoger el ícono necesitas importarlo directamente de la librería en este caso escogí `FaBeer` (una cerveza) porque es el que sale de ejemplo en la documentación.

Pareciera que estás tratando de usar un icono haciendo referencia a Icons y a un icono en específico por medio de acceso a la propiedad del objeto, haciendo:

```
Icons.`${title}`
```

El problema acá es que no puedes acceder a la propiedad de un objeto de esta manera, para que quede algo como `Icons.FaBeer` y estar accediendo a un ícono en específico, te recomendaría hacer algo como `Icons[title]` (la manera correcta de acceder a la propiedad de un objeto a través de una string) para acceder al icono que quieres, de igual manera creo que esto no es una buena idea porque estás cargando todos los íconos innecesariamente en vez de solo los que necesitas.

Te dejo el mismo ejemplo del inicio:

```js
const datos = {
  nombre: "Juan",
  edad: "25"
}

function imprimirProp(title) {
  console.log(`Esto es texto simple, con la propiedad ${title} de los datos, que es: ${datos[title]}`);
}

imprimirProp("nombre");
imprimirProp("edad");
```

Comment: No, utilizar destructuring a la hora de importar tus módulos va a reducir el tamaño del bundle de tu aplicación. Cuándo haces `import Icons from react-icons` estás cargando TODOS los iconos de la librería en vez de solo los que necesitas. Te recomiendo buscar sobre las ventajas de importar haciendo destructuración para solo cargar los íconos que necesitas.